# Nginx fails to respond - No errors in log

Tags: nginx

Starting about 4 days ago, my Nginx server started to have issues. Around 12:00 every day, the server will suddenly stop responding to requests. The server is configured to serve an Angular app over SSL.

The process will still be active and if I check the error/access logs for the time when it dies there are no fatal errors or anything of that kind, however there will be a blank spot with no access between 12:01 and whenever we noticed and restarted the service. Restarting the service completely fixes the problem.

I've checked the crontab and there is a maintenance route on the API that gets hit right before the crash (runs every hour), but running the scheduled command manually doesn't result in a crash.

I'm at a lost and don't even know where to start looking seeing as I can't replicate the problem.

Syslog at time of failure:

```
Sep 11 12:02:01 ubuntu CRON[4469]: (root) CMD (systemctl stop nginx && letsencrypt renew && systemctl restart nginx)
Sep 11 12:02:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 11 12:02:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 11 12:02:11 ubuntu CRON[4468]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Sep 11 12:05:01 ubuntu CRON[4678]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 11 12:09:01 ubuntu CRON[4932]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
Sep 11 12:15:01 ubuntu CRON[5396]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Sep 11 12:17:01 ubuntu CRON[5523]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Comment: check `/var/log/syslog` (or the equivalent for your distro/os) for any error messages about nginx at that time.

Comment: I added the log. `systemctl stop nginx && letsencrypt renew && systemctl restart nginx` didn't result in the server dying, though it is suspicious.

Comment: `systemctl stop nginx && false && systemctl restart nginx` results in nginx dying though. Maybe letsencrypt is failing when run by cron for whatever reason. I changed it so it doesn't stop before renewing (which it shouldn't anyway) and will post an answer and marked solved if I don't have any problems in the next few days.

Comment: What does the CRON do? If you disable the CRON do things work? Also run the command through CRON during your debugging and monitor things using htop